# What's the point of encrypting /boot or / partition?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, boot

I'm not talking about full disk hardware encryption. I'm talking about software encryption.

encrypting `/home` prevents your data after your laptop is stolen. As far as I understand, encrypting `/` and `/boot` is supposed to protect against running malware that steals your passwords (Evil Abigail). But that can only work when there is a fully secure and signed boot process (UEFI, bootloader, kernel). And (at least currently) [it's not the case](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/39339.html?thread=1551019). So what protection does it give?

Answer (score 3):

It prevents accidental leaks of private data that is copied around.

For example, if `/tmp` is on the `/` partition, files from your encrypted `/home` partition could be copied to the unencrypted `/tmp`, thereby making them accessible to an attacker.

By encrypting the entire system, you avoid this channel.

Comment: For the same reason the swap partition (if any) should also be encrypted.

Comment: but 'accidental leaks' is not a new vector attack that is prevented by that encryption. to rephrase question: what's the point of encrypting system binaries?

Comment: An attacker reading your harddisk (e.g. at a checkpoint) would be able to tell whether you have services with known vulnerabilities installed, which could be exploited when you turn on the machine and open the encrypted `/home` container.